# Why is page still loading? And how to use React and Chrome profilers?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-query

[**Edit**: The problem that prompted this question went away when I shut down Chrome and restarted it, but the questions below remain of interest. Plus a couple additional questions: Should the profiling or anything else (other than remembering the old [stalled car, 3 engineers joke](http://www.inflection-point.com/jokes/16.htm)) have given me any hint? And, more importantly -- is there still something wrong in the code that's causing this problem to arise after the browser has been open too long, and how might I possibly find *that* problem?]

I'm developing a react app, and it started this behavior where it appears to be loading for a very long time, but I have no idea what it's doing during this time. What I mean by it appears to be loading is that I see the X icon next to the browser url:

[image: page with stop loading icon (means it's still loading)]

When it's done, I see the reload icon:

[image: page with reload icon (means it's done loading)]

I've put breakpoints at a bunch of places, thinking that it might be repeating code or re-rendering excessively, but that's not revealing anything unexpected.

I am using react-query (and react-query-persist-client) to fetch data, but this behavior occurs even when the data has all been downloaded and is being loaded (more or less instantly) from cache. The behavior occurs after the page and data are entirely loaded and rendered.

My question is: Can anyone recommend any debugging techniques (using chrome dev tools) for finding where a React app is unexpectedly spending a lot of time? Probably profiling is the way to go, but I'm a little clueless how to get information that way.

When I try to use the React profiler, I get it to record for a while:

[image: React profiler, recording in progress]

But when I stop the recording, it tells me "No profiling data has been recorded":

[image: No profiling data has been recorded]

The chrome profiler seems to produce a lot of information, but I can't make heads or tails out of it:

[image: Chrome profiler output]

When I hover over the occasional green areas, I mostly see "Composite Layers." When I hover over the yellow areas, it's mostly saying "Timer Fired." When I try to drill in, I see stuff like this:

[image: Chrome profile output drilled down on something]

I have no idea if the function calls or "anonymous" things in the call stack (I assume it's a call stack) are from my code, deep in React code somewhere, or anything else. When I click on those code line links (like web-client-content-script.js:1:330127), it does nothing, doesn't bring me to any lines of code. Even if it did, it would probably bring me to some mysterious place in bundled code that would tell me nothing about where the problem was occurring anyway.

Many thanks for your patience if you've read this far. Any advice?